# how to call one javascript function from several similar html events

Tags: javascript

i'm calling this javascript function from a button inside html but i need to replicate the button in several places. Using the same javascript function for all the buttons doesn't seem possible to me as it kept performing the action on the first button alone, i tried renaming the function by adding digits but that will be stressful and make my code excessively bulky.
    please help.

```
  //HTML button 

 <a href="#" title="Comment" class="lk-btn" onclick="openForm()"> 

// button 1
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}
function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}

// button 2
function openForm1() {
  document.getElementById("myForm1").style.display = "block";
}
function closeForm1() {
  document.getElementById("myForm1").style.display = "none";
}

//button 3
function openForm2() {
  document.getElementById("myForm1").style.display = "block";
}
function closeForm1=2() {
  document.getElementById("myForm1").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: use jquery and with class selector you can do that.

Comment: can you please put me through on that? i'm sort of new to javascript

Comment: You need to look into function parameters. If you have two functions that do the same except for a minor detail, you pass that detail into the function as param. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics#Functions

Comment: in this case one function needs to perform the same action but in multipe html elements.

Comment: `Using the same javascript function for all the buttons doesn't seem possible to me as it kept performing the action on the first button alone` sounds like you should show your button HTML rather than your JS code. The solution is to assign the same function to multiple button's `onclick` event. Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/t9562vrz/

Comment: <a href="#" title="Comment" class="lk-btn" onclick="openForm()"> Comment</a>   this is suppose to pop up a comment box on each image on a gallery page. Using the same function (openForm()) for all other buttons only pops up the comment box on the first image alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the same function from multiple buttons this way.

You have to assign an id to each button in your HTML code and pass it to your javascript function when you call it.

**HTML Code**

```
<button type="button" onclick="openForm(this)" id="1">Button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="openForm(this)" id="2">Button2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="openForm(this)" id="3">Button3</button>
```

**JS Function**

```
function openForm(elem) { 
    alert("Calling openForm() from Button " + elem.id); 
}
```

**Update :  To use without assigning the IDs**

```
<button type="button" onclick="openForm()" >Button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="openForm()" >Button2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="openForm()" >Button3</button>

function openForm() {
    alert("Calling openForm()");
}
```

Comment: This could work... Except that it's a gallery page and i've got quite a number of image which mean assigning id to all of them manually. A bit tedious ;)

Comment: You can still use it without assigning the IDs. I have updated my answer. Check if that helps you.

Comment: i guess i'll have to keep this for future reference :), i already found a way around it. But thanks for helping. Really appreciate

Comment: Alright. But please up vote my answer if you think it's a possible solution or a workaround to your problem. So that it will be helpful to someone who has a similar problem to spot it. Also, share your answer with others as well.